# Integrating App with Facebook getting error code #1732910

Tags: android, facebook, api, session

I am integrating my app with facebook so users can post to their timeline. I had this working previously and I have double checked the app dashboard and compared this to my key hash and app id that i am using and still the user cannot post. The user can log in, but when trying to open the session it stays in opening then changes to close_login_failed. While debugging it, i get the facebook exception and the log in is aborted. I get toast pop up with an error code when the user is using the app that says to contact facebook. The error code is #1732910. I have tried using the keytool from both java 1.6 and 1.7 as well re-downloading the openssl as this worked from some users. However, my key hash remains the same. I have added the debug and the signed release key hashes to the app dashboard and still no luck. Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: What SDK version are you using, and what version of the Facebook app does the user have?

Comment: Any update on this? Did you tested this on several Androids? I get that error on a ZTE 2.3.6 phone, while it works on another 2.3.6 and on a Wiko 4.1.2, so I doubt the error is with the hash. Does anyone knows what #1732910 stands for anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, leaving the answer here for future visitors to this link even if its 10 years later from the question.

This error code was occurring to me because of a mismatch between the package I had set up on my app/build.gradle -> applicationId and the "Package Name" configured on the Facebook Login settings for Android.

I believe this error could happen for different reasons.. but this is worth checking.